# Linkit mt7688 LEDE firmware creates strange symbols

Tags: openwrt

I have Linkit mt7688 devices and currently using LEDE firmware in them. These strange symbols seems to be created by the system itself. Because after some use of the device or even when first booting it there are these symbols. [image]

What can cause this ? Is there a way to clear this ? After installing a new firmware these symbols are still remain. Is this a hardware problem ?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like there is a difference in Baud rate between the U-Boot and The main firmware. The default baud rate for Linkit 7688 is 57600.