# Files in /root with filename containing strange characters

Tags: filenames, openwrt

I am using Linkit 7688 OpenWRT. There are some files are getting created with indefinite time.

```
root@OpenWRT:~# ls /
,��U�^E�^B           mnt                  sys     proc                 usr
bin                  rom                  var
dev                  root                 www
etc                  sbin                 ���k��Y�H��R����Ң�
lib
```

[Another post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/467285/117549) mentioned it is because difference between U-Boot and the main firmware.

As in my case: There is *no difference* between U-Boot and the main firmware. We are still facing issue. How we can delete these files? How these can be avoided?

```
#~ cat /proc/cmdline 
console=ttyS2,57600 rootfstype=squashfs,jffs2
```

Comment: What's mounted in /, `cat /proc/mounts`? I haven't used OpenWRT in a long while, IIRC it was some overlay construction between readonly squashfs and user storage. Either one could be corrupt and then you might just have to re-install OpenWRT from scratch. Also test for bad ram.

Comment: root@OpenWRT:~# cat /proc/mounts 
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
/dev/root /rom squashfs ro,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime 0 0
/dev/mtdblock6 /overlay jffs2 rw,noatime 0 0
overlayfs:/overlay / overlay rw,noatime,lowerdir=/,upperdir=/overlay/upper,workdir=/overlay/work 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,size=512k,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,mode=600 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,noatime 0 0